# CXF doesn't honor keep-alive request by the client

Tags: http, soap, cxf, keep-alive

My client is sending:

```
POST /xxx/yyy HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9009
User-Agent: gSOAP/2.8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2442
Connection: keep-alive
SOAPAction: ""
```

But the server replies:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 11182
Server: Jetty(8.1.14.v20131031)
```

Isn't the server supposed to return "Connection: keep-alive" too?
I see that afterwards the client closes the connection although it is configure to keep the connection open.
I assumed it is because the server didn't provide the keep-alive in the reply (Is that the RFC?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the reason gSoap closed the connection wasn't related to the HTTP headers returned from server, but to the fact you need to specify the keep-alive flags on both directions by calling:

```
    soap_set_imode(this, SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE);
    soap_set_omode(this, SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE);
```

From what I've read in HTTP 1.1 persistent connections are the default so if the server didn't return "Connection: close" the connection can be used for next request too.

Answer (score 0):

If the server you are sending to doesn't request keep-alive, then CXF (actually the Java classes CXF uses) will keep the connection open for 5 seconds.  This behavior cannot be modified in Java versions before Java 19.  In Java 19, a new setting was added, which allows you to set the keep-alive timeout, in the case where the server doesn't specify it.  To set the keep-alive time to 1 minute, you can do this (only in Java 19 and higher):

```
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive.time.server", "60");
```